# How to count a number of character in each element of array in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I count number of letter "a" into every element of the array?

```
let a = ['Guatemala', 'Canada', 'Costa Rica', 'Anguilla', 'North Korea'];
```

I try to use `split()` method, but could not finish ....

```
let a = ['Guatemala', 'Canada', 'Costa Rica', 'Anguilla', 'North Korea'];
let newA = a.toString();

for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  let newAr = a[i].split(',');

  for(j = 0; j < newAr.length; j++) {
    console.log(newAr[j].split(','));
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: *"but cannot to finish"* What's unfinished? What result do you expect, and what are you getting instead? (And why are you turning your array into a string?)

Comment: Please don't tag-spam. This has nothing to do with [tag:function], or [tag:html] for instance.

Answer (score 2):

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

[String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

> The `match()` method retrieves the matches when matching a string against a regular expression.

You can use `map()` and `match()` to get the array of count in each string item:

```js
let a = ['Guatemala', 'Canada', 'Costa Rica', 'Anguilla', 'North Korea'];

let aCountArr = a.map(i => {
  return i.match(/a/g).length;
});
console.log(aCountArr);
```

**OR:** You can use [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

> The for...of statement creates a loop iterating over iterable objects, including: built-in String, Array, Array-like objects (e.g., arguments or NodeList), TypedArray, Map, Set, and user-defined iterables. It invokes a custom iteration hook with statements to be executed for the value of each distinct property of the object.

```js
let a = ['Guatemala', 'Canada', 'Costa Rica', 'Anguilla', 'North Korea'];

let aCountArr = [];
for(let c of a){
  aCountArr.push(c.match(/a/g).length)
}
console.log(aCountArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I count number of letter "a" into every element of the array?

If the goal is to end up with a new array with the counts of how many `a`s there are in the word in the first array, then `map` and `reduce` should do it:

```js
let a = ['Guatemala', 'Canada', 'Costa Rica', 'Anguilla', 'North Korea'];
let result = a.map(entry =>
    Array.from(entry).reduce((counter, ch) =>
        ch === "a" ? counter + 1 : counter,
        0
    )
);
console.log(result);
```

`map` loops through the original array letting us process each entry and produce a result for it. We turn the string into an array of characters, then use `reduce` to count how many of those are `a`s.

There are about eighteen other ways. :-) For instance, we could use `replace` to remove all characters that aren't `a` and take the length:

```js
let a = ['Guatemala', 'Canada', 'Costa Rica', 'Anguilla', 'North Korea'];
let result = a.map(entry =>
    entry.replace(/[^a]/g, "").length
);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @ЕлисейГорьков - Yes, absolutely. Both of the loops above (`map` and `reduce`/`replace`) could be replaced with `for` loops.

Comment: can you give an exapmle?

Comment: @ЕлисейГорьков - I think with just a small amount of research you'll find lots of examples of `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

Get count for every element in array:

```js
let a = ['Guatemala', 'Canada', 'Costa Rica', 'Anguilla', 'North Korea'];
let count = a.map(el => el.match(/a/g).length);
console.log(count);
```

Get count for entire array as whole:

```js
let a = ['Guatemala', 'Canada', 'Costa Rica', 'Anguilla', 'North Korea'];
let count = a.join('').match(/a/g).length;
console.log(count);
```